# How to edit cell toolbar while using .ipynb in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am not able to see buttons such as "Execute cell and below" and "Execute above cell" in either the floating cell toolbar or the main toolbar at the top. I have seen these buttons present in toolbars in screenshots from web articles, but couldn't find any relevant resource.

(As for the extensions, I have Jupyter, Jupyter Keymap, and Jupyter Notebook Renderers)

[Attaching screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQLx6.png)

Comment: Are the latest versions of jupyter and python extensions installed? If possible, can you explain what system you are using, the version of vscode and the extension you are using, the settings in your `settings.json`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

setting `"notebook.consolidatedRunButton": true` will give you the extra commands shown in that screenshot. With that set to false, they should show up in the cell toolbar:

[image]